# Can Naegleria fowleri enter through the eyes ( example rinsing/splashing eyes with water)

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, parasitism

I understand that it primarily enters the body through the nose by by "feeding on the olfactory neurons in the nose" as answered here in a [different question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/820/1306). Would the nerve cells in the eyes present a similar entryway?

Comment: @Gabriel could you perhaps opine on this?

Answer (score 2):

In a 1987 article ["Nonenteric Infections Acquired through Contact with Water"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/4454035.pdf?acceptTC=true), the author mentioned that "Infection of the ears, throat, respiratory tract, and **cornea** are also encountered" by virulent strains of *Acanthamoeba* and *Naegleria fowleri*. The only reference that implicates Naegleria fowleri is [this one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6617613), but it doesn't mention modes of infection.

**The long and the short of it is that *Acanthamoeba* infections can be acquired through contact with the cornea, but it's not clear whether *Naegleria* infections can also be acquired in this way.**

n.b. The first link takes you to the JSTOR page.  In the event you do not have access, here is the [PubMed page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3547578).

Comment: Is the extract you quoted specific to Naegleria fowleri or just water borne pathogens in general? Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Jarnal: I edited the post to answer your comment-question, but I am aware that this doesn't answer the original question. I cannot provide that answer; I only delved into the article posted by ohcanada.

Comment: @dd3, thanks, your input provided helpful clarification.